# Is there an equivalent in Ubuntu to /var/log/yum.log in Redhat?

Tags: package-management, log

Redhat has a log you can look at after yum installs packages on your system. Is there an equivalent log to that in Ubuntu?

Comment: I would say it's _related_, but not quite exactly a duplicate, even if the answers are similar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Ubuntu the high-level package manager is APT. There's a directory `/var/log/apt` which contains

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
```

which lists APT commands, who ran them, and what was installed, upgraded or removed.

and

```
/var/log/apt/term.log
```

which logs the output of APT commands.

The lower level package manager is `dpkg`. In the file

```
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

You can see package status updates made by `dpkg`.

If a log is empty, it has been rotated. Look for files like `dpkg.log.1` or a `.gz` file (readable with `zless`) - these are older logs.

Answer (score 7):

`/var/log/apt` contains the log entries concerning packages installed by `apt` on Ubuntu.

There are two sets of entries, `history`, which shows a list of packages and the actions taken:

```
Start-Date: 2017-12-01  08:49:50
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.5, 57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2, 52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), thunderbird:amd64 (52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2, 52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), firefox:amd64 (57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.5, 57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2, 52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2, 52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
End-Date: 2017-12-01  08:50:21
```

and `term`, which shows the output of the terminal commands that were processed.

```
Log started: 2017-12-01  08:49:50
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 330191 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox_57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox (57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../firefox-locale-en_57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-locale-en (57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird-locale-en_1%3a52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking thunderbird-locale-en (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (1:52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird_1%3a52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking thunderbird (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (1:52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird-gnome-support_1%3a52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking thunderbird-gnome-support (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (1:52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird-locale-en-us_1%3a52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking thunderbird-locale-en-us (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (1:52.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Setting up firefox (57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
Setting up firefox-locale-en (57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-gnome-support (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en-us (1:52.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Log ended: 2017-12-01  08:50:21
```

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu and all other distributions from the Debian ecosystem use the package manager `apt` instead of `yum`.

Therefore, you can find its logs inside the directory `/var/log/apt`.

Most important is the `history.log` file in that location, which briefly logs all package operations (installed, upgraded, removed packages...). The other one is `term.log`, which logs the complete terminal output of all `apt` invocations.

Note that due to log rotation, old log files will be regularly (about once per month) compressed and renamed by appending an index number (and the compression ending `.gz`), so that the highest number indicates the oldest compressed log. Example: `history.log.3.gz`